# Qual é a finalidade do Array and String Dereferencing implementado no PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, array, string

No manual do PHP, podemos ver nas **New Features** a funcionalidade de [Array and String literal Dereferencing](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.new-features.php).

**Exemplo:**

```
echo 'string'[2]; // r
echo ['stack', 'overflow'][1]; //overflow
```

Pensando no caso de se obter um **índice** de uma *string* ou *array*, já funcionaria em outras versões do PHP, desde que o Array ou a string estivessem numa variável.

```
$var = 'string';
echo $var[2]; // 'r'
```

No PHP 5.4, eu sei que já temos agora o acesso direto aos membros de um *array* que são retornados por uma função, e que é muito útil por sinal (**Function array dereferencing**).

Mas, no caso do PHP 5.5, eu não entendo qual é a finalidade de obter um valor, através de um índice, diretamente de uma string ou de um *array*, já que estes não estão atribuidos a uma variável?

Pra mim, não faria nenhum sentido o programador fazer uso do primeiro exemplo acima.

Existe alguma finalidade mais robusta do que a do primeiro exemplo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O exemplo da documentação é infeliz (que novidade, né?). Na forma como foi colocado, onde tudo é constante, não há vantagem mesmo. A documentação deveria ajudar entender a finalidade disto, mas preferiram uma abordagem burocrática.

Usando

```
echo ['stack', 'overflow'][$x];
```

é "melhor" (ou pelo menos o código fica mais simplificado) que fazer

```
switch ($x) {
    case 0: 
        echo 'stack';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'overflow';
        break;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/t6VNgE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ifjyxakx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ArrayDereferencing.php).

Então é usado primariamente para simplificação de código. Imagine se tiver 10, 20, 30 elementos neste *array*, como o `switch` ficaria longo.

E de certa forma para manter um padrão. Se outras operações podem ser feitas diretamente com literais, por que não esta? Operações devem ser feitas em cima de valores e não em cima de variáveis. Se por acaso um valor vem de uma variável, de um retorno de uma função, uma expressão ou de um literal não deveria fazer diferença. Se isto tivesse sido conceituado corretamente quando a linguagem foi criada, existiria esta forma desde a versão 1.0. Só o PHP mesmo para fazer esta confusão.

Comment: Boa a sua resposta. Depois do seu exemplo, imaginei uma usabilidade com strings, que poderia ser:
`$string = '/Minha string/';
echo trim($string, '/')[0]; //M`

Comment: Uma questão a esclarecer é que, quando digo "não está atribuído à variável", me refiro ao fato de que nós, programadores, temos que manipular strings e arrays geralmente de fontes externas (como DB, um arquivo ou $_POST), e isso requer que as mesmas estejam em variáveis (ou em algum retorno de um método ou função). 

Dificilmente alguém declararia uma string literal pra obter a primeira letra valendo-se dessa funcionalidade, já que ele já sabe que letra é essa e seria mais fácil escrevê-la lá.

por isso é que citei sobre variáveis. Uma string "conhecida" não precisaria desse tratamento

Comment: Como eu disse, o uso com constante no índice não é muito vantajoso.

Comment: é impressionante como as pessoas acham utilidades excelentes para funções que a primeira vista são completamente inúteis.. +1