# Não consigo printar a array no servidor

Tags: php

localmente os dados saem, mas hospedado não funciona.

```
function teste(){
    return array(
        "importancia" => array(
            "Customer el",
            "Over ",
            "Ovedde (MPG)"
        ),
        "dados"=> array(
            "Customer care: xthe sdsdel",
            "Overall d.",
            "asd"
        ),
        "question"=> array(
            "Icvxcv",
            "Iasdasd"
        )
    );
}


$teste = teste()['importancia'];
echo count($teste);
```

localmente aparece o echo = 3;
agora quando eu hospedo a página no servidor, a página fica simplesmente em branco.

A versão do host externo é a 5.3.3-7 e a instalada no meu computador é a 5.5.9.

Comment: Qual a versão do php na hospedagem e no seu localhost?

Comment: desculpa a ignorância, mas como eu vejo a versão do php na minha hospedagem?

Comment: crie um arquivo novo com esse conteudo: `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze26

Comment: ``PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze26 -> servidor`` ||
``5.5.9 -> local``

Answer (score 1):

O jeito é adaptar a sintaxe do php para a versão 5.3, é bem simples, pegue o retorno da função e faça a chamada da chave em `count()`.

Essa funcionalidade [array e string literal dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.const-dereferencing), está disponivel nas versões 5.5 ou superior do php.

```
$teste = teste();
echo count($teste['importancia']);
```

**Relacionado:**

[Qual é a finalidade do Array and String Dereferencing implementado no PHP 5.5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23400/91)